# Where is the inner implementation of "form submit" in webkit of Android

Tags: android, web, webkit

In a browser, if I want to submit a form containing a username and a password input, I only need to add an "action" attribute and set the "method" attribute to "post":

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="https://www.xxx">
  <input id="username" type="text" value="xxxxxx" name="username">
  <input id="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

then the browser will handle the post and concatenate the password and username as the request and send to the server.

My question is: in the webkit (what I concern is the Android webkit, but I think others will be ok)，where is the code of handling such process? Can I find the code that get the text from the input element, concatenate them, and then send to the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

where there's no answer, I finally find it.
For webkit, there's mainly four directory we need to consider in android:

for java part:

- framework/base/core/java/androud/webkit

for native c part

- external/webkit/Source/WebCore
- external/webkit/Source/WebKit
- external/webkit/Source/JavaScriptCore

for the form submit, the java part webkit will send a key event which will be handled by C WebCore.

we can see the code from

- WebCore/html/HTMLFormElement.cpp
- WebCore/loader/FormSubmission.cpp
- WebCore/loader/FrameLoader.cpp